# Skew textarea to a diamond form, without distorting the text

Tags: html, css, textarea, skew

Here is my question. I want to have a textarea in a diamond form without any distortion in the text (like the image attached).
Can you help me please?
Thanks

[image: this is what I want to achieve]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I have tried skew ( transform: skewY(30deg) ) but is deformes the text.

Comment: Include an image of how you want the text to look.

Comment: I have already attached the image in the question. exactly as the image above.

Comment: and how should the text look if not distorted?

Comment: I edited the question. apparently I did not express myself verywell. the image is actualy what I want.